# Leer valor de un array json_encode laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, array

Hice una `query` a la base de datos (`BD`) la cual después transforme por medio `json_encode()` para mostrarla en la vista `blade` y el resultado es este:

```
[{"monto":"44"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"5640"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"0"},{"monto":"456"},{"monto":"186685"},{"monto":"0"}]
```

el problema es que no se como obtener un valor en especifico de ese arreglo.

Comment: Y cual es el valor que quieres y como has intentado obtenerlo?

Comment: trate de hacer esto para pescar el primer valor de monto {{$totalmes[0][0]}} pero me devuelve el primer carácter que es el [ corchete de abrir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es en javascript totalmes[0].monto